# How to avoid multiple nodes with the same tag in xml with namespace using jQuery 'find'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, wcf, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML

```
<ProjectResponse xmlns="Services.Messages" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
  <Projects xmlns:a="Services.DTO">
    <a:Project>
      <a:ID>113</a:ID>
      <a:Name>Test project</a:Name>
      <a:Documents>
        <a:ProjectDocument>
          <a:FileName>DS.docx</a:FileName>
          <a:ID>65</a:ID>
          <a:ProjectID>113</a:ProjectID>
        </a:ProjectDocument>        
      </a:Documents>
    </a:Project>
  </Projects>
</ProjectResponse>
```

When i perform $(this).find('[nodeName=a:ID]') in 'each' function i get 2 IDs, one from Project and another from Document.

```
$(projectsXml).find('Projects').children().each(function() {
            var projectId = $(this).find('[nodeName=a:ID]').text();
```

The question is how can i get only Project ID, not Document ID and another IDs that can occur ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) instead of [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) inside as well, so it only looks for *immediate* children, like this:

```
$(projectsXml).find('Projects').children().each(function() {
  var projectId = $(this).children('[nodeName=a:ID]').text();
});
```

Comment: please check these question and tell me the mistake http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591761/how-to-compare-the-value-with-xml-data